# Doesnt receive coins into BitcoinD Daemon

Tags: bitcoin, bitcoind, blockchain

I have installed **bitcoind daemon** into my server and create address for individual users. An **User A sends 0.005 BTC** into my **Bitcoind daemon server**, yet it will not appears into my server. I have checked using the following commands:

```
getreceivedbyaddress()

listaccounts()

listreceivedbyaddress()
```

Following [Link](https://blockchain.info/address/1JB1XynGv9MGHSuYSc9CnmM5egS27CGGvF) will generate acknowledgement from user transaction.It will show transaction history, yet it will not receive coin into my bitcoind daemon server.

Please kindly advice me. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you see the transction in the blockchain? Perhaps it's not been processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are sending the commands to Bitcoind make sure you are sending in the minimum confirmations count of 0, this should show your Bitcoins.  Change the number passed in to return the balance based on how many confirmations are required. I'm not sure which language your using but the call may look something like this, where 0 is the minimum confirmations required.

```
client.getReceivedByAddress('1HB5XMLmzFVj8ALj6mfBsbifRoD4miY36v',0);
```